# Is there a specific grammar on Atom for .ejs files?

Tags: javascript, jsx, ejs, atom-editor

I ask this because when I am writing an .ejs file, if the grammar selected is Javascript, my EJS syntax doesn't get highlighted, but when I select Javascript (JSX) as grammar, then my EJS syntax gets highlighted, so now I'm using Javascript (JSX) grammar on all my .ejs files.

I thought JSX was only used for React, but somehow it's working for my .ejs files, and it makes it easier for me to write and read the code.

Is it ok to do this, or will this bring me any problems with my code later on? Or is there a specific grammar for EJS files on Atom? I cannot seem to find any.

Nor I can't seem to find a specific EJS package that will highlight syntax. I might be wrong though, but total newbie here.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

Atom only has syntax highlighting for limited languages as a default. You can install additional packages by going to `Preferences` and then the `Install` tab. From there you can search for “ejs” and see what you can find.

I’d try installing this package: https://atom.io/packages/language-ejs

Comment: Many languages don’t have default support in Atom, and require additional packages to get syntax highlighting.

Comment: Thanks for the help, Alexander. I went to install that package and then noticed I had already installed it, but somehow it wasn't working. I clicked on the packages "settings" button and it says the following:

"Select 'JavaScript Template' if it's not automatically working."

But I have no idea what that means. I see no checkbox or option to select JavaScript Template" or anything like that.

Comment: Not sure about issues specific to the package. If you have EJS selected as your grammar it should work. Otherwise you might be able to find another ejs package or open an issue on the package’s repo.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the advice.